# Como modificar las categorías en un gráfico en matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Dada una lista con las categorías para el eje x de un gráfico.

```
tamiz= ["2", "1 1/2","1", "3/4", "1/2", "3/8", "1/4", "4", "10", "40", "100", "200"]
```

Y otra con la abertura de cada uno

```
tamizAbertura = [ 50.0,   38.10,  25.0,  19.0,  12.5,   9.5,  6.3,   4.75,  2.0, 0.425, 0.150, 0.075]
```

Necesito realizar un gráfico logarítmico, en donde en el eje x se marquen los logaritmos de `tamizAbertura`, pero se tiene que ver las etiquetas de `tamiz`

Mi pregunta es como puedo cambiar, matplotlib escribe en el eje x los valores de las columnas, pero necesito escribir los str de los tamices

El Codigo que estoy usando para graficar es:

```
# Graficas
# Sub-Grafico: 1
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Grafica de los pesos pasa tamiz')
plt.ylabel('Peso pasa tamiz')
plt.xlabel('Tamiz')
plt.plot(tamiz,pesopt,'o-',markersize=8, label='Peso pasa tamiz')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.grid()

# Sub-Grafico: 2
plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Curva Granulometrica')
plt.ylabel('Pasa tamiz')
plt.xlabel('Tamiz')
plt.semilogx(tamizAbertura,granulometria,'o-',markersize=8, data=None, label='Porciento pasa tamiz')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
ax=plt.gca()
ax.grid(True, which='both', axis='both', linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, sería conveniente que agregaras el código que usas ahora mismo para generar la gráfica y así  tener un ejemplo reproducible sobre el que basarse. Básicamente lo que quieres es usar `tamiz` para asignar las etiquetas del eje `x` ¿No?

Comment: Eso mismo, que no me aparezcan los numeros de `tamizAbertura` , sino los str de `tamiz`

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido correctamente, para hacer lo que quieres necesitarías seguir dos pasos:

- Asignar los valores propios de `tamizAbertura` como marcas del eje <kbd>X</kbd> mediante `ax.set_xticks`
- Cambiar las etiquetas de las marcas asignadas usando la lista `tamiz` mediante `ax.set_xtickslabels`.

Opcionalmente puedes eliminar todas las marcas menores del eje <kbd>X</kbd> así como las lineas correspondientes de la rejilla. Un ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

tamiz= ["2", "1 1/2","1", "3/4", "1/2", "3/8", "1/4", "4", "10", "40", "100", "200"]
tamizAbertura = [ 50.0,   38.10,  25.0,  19.0,  12.5,   9.5,  6.3,   4.75,  2.0, 0.425, 0.150, 0.075]
pesopt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
granulometria = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]


# Graficas
# Sub-Grafico: 1
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Grafica de los pesos pasa tamiz')
plt.ylabel('Peso pasa tamiz')
plt.xlabel('Tamiz')
plt.plot(tamiz,pesopt,'o-',markersize=8, label='Peso pasa tamiz')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.grid()

# Sub-Grafico: 2
plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Curva Granulometrica')
plt.ylabel('Pasa tamiz')
plt.xlabel('Tamiz')

plt.semilogx(tamizAbertura,granulometria,'o-',markersize=8, data=None, label='Porciento pasa tamiz')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True, which='major', axis='both', linestyle='--')
ax.set_xticks(tamizAbertura)
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', size=0)
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', width=0) 
ax.set_xticklabels(tamiz)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]